# Scale UI Image source image

Tags: layout, unity-game-engine, unityscript, unity3d-gui

I have a **UI Image** whose *Source Image* is assigned at runtime. These images will be of various sizes and I need them to be scaled to fit the bounds of the layout element so that the entire image is visible.

I have tried a number of approaches for this, however I can’t seem to get this to work; could anyone please provide me some pointers on how to achieve this?

Many thanks in advance

**NB**: the layout is controlled via *Layout Group* components, which conflicts for control over the rect with other potentially useful layout components such as *Aspect Ratio Fitter* and *Content Sizer* (as mentioned in documented solves for this issue)

```js
public
function ContextImgImp() {

  Debug.Log("Context Img Located at: " + texLocation);

  var wwwDirectory = "file://" + texLocation; //this will probably need to change for other OS (PC = file:/ [I think?]) - **REVISE**
  Debug.Log("Tex located at: " + wwwDirectory);

  newImgTex = new Texture2D(512, 512, TextureFormat.DXT1, false);

  while (true) {

    var www: WWW = new WWW(wwwDirectory);

    yield www;

    Debug.Log("Done Downloading Texture");
    www.LoadImageIntoTexture(newImgTex);

    if (www.isDone) {
      break; //if done downloading image break loop
    }
  }

  var imgSprite = contImg.sprite;
  var imgRect = imgSprite.rect;
  var imgPivot = imgRectTrans.pivot;
  var pixelScale = 100;
  Debug.Log("Pixel Scale:" + pixelScale);

  newImgSprite = Sprite.Create(newImgTex, imgRect, imgPivot, pixelScale);
  contImg.sprite = newImgSprite;

  //imgRectTrans.rect.size = Vector2(130,130);
  //contImg.sprite.rect.size = Vector2(130,130);
  //contImg.type = Image.Type.Simple;

  //***HERE*** 
  if (assetFromFile) {
    ImgNameSplit(); //only execute namesplit if from file
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There is the "SetNativeSize" function, however if you are using layout components then this size will be overridden on the next update loop.